# Flask WTForms cause unknow error in Mysql query when submit Form

Tags: python, mysql, flask

The error :

```
ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE UID = -1' at line 1
```

**Here is my view.py**

```
@app.route("/profile/", methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def profile_page():

UID=current_user.UID
User=models.User(UID)
user_type=User.get_type()
application_year = User.get_application_year()
User_name = User.get_uname()
life_cost = User.get_estimated_cost()
email = User.get_email()

form = forms.profile_form(request.form)
SE = User.get_if_SE()
APs = User.get_nAP()


SAT_score = User.get_sat_score()
ACT_score = User.get_act_score()
new_SAT_score = User.get_new_sat_score()
TOEFL = User.get_TOEFL()
GPA = User.get_gpa()
SE = User.get_if_SE()
APs = User.get_nAP()


user ={'uname': User_name, 'UID':UID, 'year': application_year, 'email':email, 'User_type':user_type}
scores = {'SAT':SAT_score,'ACT':ACT_score,'new_SAT': new_SAT_score, 'TOEFL':TOEFL, 'GPA': GPA}

if  request.method=="POST":

    User.set_uname(form.uname.data)
    User.set_email(form.email.data)
    User.set_year(form.year.data)

    User.set_gpa(form.gpa.data)
    User.set_toefl_score(form.toefl_score.data)
    User.set_act_score(form.test_score_ACT.data)
    User.set_sat_score(form.test_score_SAT.data)
    User.set_new_sat_score(form.test_score_new_sat.data)
    User.set_estimated_cost(form.life_cost.data)

    print form.uname.data
    print form.email.data


return render_template('profile.html', User=user, score=scores, form=form)
```

**Here is my related Models.py**

```
class SQLModel:
def __init__(self):
    self.select_uq_q = "SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s = %s LIMIT 1;"
    self.select_q = "SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s = %s;"
    self.update_uq_q = "UPDATE %s SET %s = %s WHERE %s = %s LIMIT 1;"
    self.update_q = "UPDATE %s SET %s = %s WHERE %s = %s;"
    self.insert_q = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s);"

    def __update(self, field, new_val):
    """
    helper function to update a specific field to a new value
    """
    if type(new_val) == str:
        new_val = "'" + new_val + "'"

    query = self.update_q % (C.TABLES['USER_TABLE'], field, str(new_val),
            'UID', str(self.UID))

    SQLConnector.execute(query)

    def set_uname(self, uname):

    self.__update('uname', uname)
```

**Here is the html**

```
            <form method="POST">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ form.email.label }}{{ form.email(class="validate", value=User.email )}}
            {{ form.year.label }}{{ form.year(class="validate", value=User.year )}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
        <div class="card-content white-text">
            <span class="card-title">Scores</span>
            {{ form.toefl_score.label }}{{ form.toefl_score(class="validate", value=score.TOEFL )}}
            {{ form.test_score_SAT.label }}{{ form.test_score_SAT(class="validate", value=score.SAT )}}
            {{ form.test_score_ACT.label }}{{ form.test_score_ACT(class="validate", value=score.ACT )}}
            {{ form.test_score_new_sat.label }}{{ form.test_score_new_sat(class="validate", value=score.new_SAT )}}
            {{ form.gpa.label }}{{ form.gpa(class="validate", value=score.GPA )}}
            <input type='submit'>
        </form>
```

Everything is Okay when I do it in a terminal.

Comment: It must be have some error in your SQL.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Use an existing orm framework like sqlalchemy, which integrates well with flask.

Comment: It looks like you build a bike when other people are already driving on this. [Try this](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/quickstart/) and forget your mistakes, sql injections etc.